# Writing a password validation form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am a beginning developer and have been trying to write a validation form using javascript. The validation popups don't seem to occur. Could someone please look at my code and tell me what I am missing?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="udacity-grader" content="http://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/tests.json" libraries="jsgrader" unit-tests="http://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/unit_tests.js">
    <title>Quiz - setCustomValidity</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Create a new password</h3>
    <p>Password should meet the following requirements:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>16-100 characters (longer is better)</li>
        <li>At least one of these symbols: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *</li>
        <li>At least one number</li>
        <li>At least one lowercase letter</li>
        <li>At least one uppercase letter</li>
    </ul>

    <label>
        <input id="first" type="password" placeholder="New password" min="16" max="100" autofocus>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input id="second" type="password" min="16" max="100"placeholder="Repeat password">
    </label>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');
var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#second');
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

submit.onclick = function() {
    if(firstPasswordInput != secondPasswordInput){
        secondPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password does not match');
    }
    if (firstPasswordInput.includes('/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*]/g')== false)
    {    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include one of the following !@#$%^&*');
    }
    if (firstPasswordInput.includes('/[0-9]/g')== false)
    {    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include a number');
    }
    if (firstPasswordInput.includes('/[a-z]/g')== false)
    {    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include a lowercase letter');
    }
    if (firstPasswordInput.includes('/[A-Z]/g')== false)
    {    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include an uppercase letter');
    }
    };
```

Comment: Why are you limiting passwords to max 100 char?

Comment: Hey, i think you forgot to put your javascript in `<script>` and `</script>` tags ;)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('#first')` will return the input element, if you need to look at the value, you must use `.value`:

```
var firstElement = document.querySelector('#first');
var firstValue = document.querySelector('#first').value
```

You cannot use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method on an element, it is a string method.

And [`setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) is an element method.

```js
var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');

var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#second');
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

submit.onclick = function() {

  var firstPasswordInputValue = firstPasswordInput.value;
  var secondPasswordInputValue = secondPasswordInput.value;

  console.log('submit');
  if (firstPasswordInputValue != secondPasswordInputValue) {
    secondPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password does not match');
  }
  if (firstPasswordInputValue.includes('/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*]/g') == false) {
    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include one of the following !@#$%^&*');
  }
  if (firstPasswordInputValue.includes('/[0-9]/g') == false) {
    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include a number');
  }
  if (firstPasswordInputValue.includes('/[a-z]/g') == false) {
    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include a lowercase letter');
  }
  if (firstPasswordInputValue.includes('/[A-Z]/g') == false) {
    firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('password must include an uppercase letter');
  }
};
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="udacity-grader" content="http://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/tests.json" libraries="jsgrader" unit-tests="http://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/unit_tests.js">
  <title>Quiz - setCustomValidity</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Create a new password</h3>
  <p>Password should meet the following requirements:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>16-100 characters (longer is better)</li>
    <li>At least one of these symbols: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *</li>
    <li>At least one number</li>
    <li>At least one lowercase letter</li>
    <li>At least one uppercase letter</li>
  </ul>

  <label>
        <input id="first" type="password" placeholder="New password" min="16" max="100" autofocus>
    </label>
  <label>
        <input id="second" type="password" min="16" max="100"placeholder="Repeat password">
    </label>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for pointing it out, i fixed the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the inputs inside a form. The input submit works on sending the request before the javascript code works, so try using a button instead of an input type submit, then after all the checks, call the form and submit it.
However,

```
var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');
```

only returns the input element so try getting `firstPasswordInput .value`
Hope this helps you!